# OSX Mavericks, how to debug local rails app email issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, osx-mavericks, mail-server

I have a couple of rails apps using versions ree-1.8.7-2011.03 and ruby-1.9.2-p180. Before the upgrade I was using Lion, and sending emails (eg. forgot password etc.) worked fine. However, now, no emails seem to be sending at all.

I also have a bunch of php sites in my "Webserver/Documents" folder that work fine and can send test emails from within each site.

Ive searched a lot for a fix and could only find some 'postfix' settings changes, but nothing seems to be working. Im very new to rails and am wondering what are the best ways to debug this? It cant be anything in the rails code because it was all working fine before the upgrade to mavericks.

Any ideas greatly appreciated, Im stuck here. Thanks

Comment: Anyone any other thoughts on this? Im completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but perhaps an alternative solution.  Unless you really need to *send* emails in development, consider an alternative like letter_opener which will write out the contents and pop a new browser tab showing you what would have been sent.

https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener

Works very well for me and I don't have to muck around ensuring my mac can send email.  Nor do I worry that I'll accidentally email someone with development info.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Philip, Ill probably look at that if all else fails. Ideally id still want the emails to go through though. Has to be something simple :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok its been a couple of months but hopefully this will help someone else out. All my emails worked while running

`rake jobs:work`